Proving that $E_{\gamma }\left( z \right) \cdot E_{\gamma }\left( -z \right) \geqslant 1$
I want to prove that
$$E_{\gamma }\left( z \right) \cdot E_{\gamma }\left( -z \right) =\sum^{+\infty }_{k=0} \frac{z^{k}}{\Gamma \left( k\gamma +1 \right) } \cdot \sum^{+\infty }_{k=0} \frac{\left( -z \right)^{k} }{\Gamma \left( k\gamma +1 \right) } \geqslant 1$$
where $z\in R$, $\gamma \in \left( 0,1 \right)$, and $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function.
I tried to find the derivative to determine the monotonicity, but the derivative is too complicated for me to determine.and I think if we can prove when $\gamma \in \left( 0,1 \right) \cap Q$ is correct, then QED.

Please use MathJax and show your work.

What have you tried? Is there any context for this question?

I tried to find the derivative to determine the monotonicity, but the derivative is too complicated for me to determine

and I think if we can prove when \gamma \in \left( 0,1 \right) \cap Q is correct, then QED

Please put this in the question (by editing it) even if it doesn't seem to get you anywhere. If you don't show your efforts then the question will probably get closed

ok, however, I don not know how to convert latex formula into math formula, can anybody help me to edit it?

Can you show $E’_\gamma(z) \geq 0$ for $z \geq 0$?

$E^{{}{\gamma }\prime }\left( z \right) \geqslant 0\  for\  z\geqslant 0$ is obvious, but we need show $E^{{}{\gamma }\prime }\left( z \right) \cdot E_{\gamma }\left( -z \right) -E_{\gamma }\left( z \right) \cdot E^{\prime }_{\gamma }\left( -z \right) \geqslant 0\  for\  z\geqslant 0$

You know that $f(x) := E_\gamma(-x)E_\gamma(x)$ is an even function with $f(0) = 1$. The derivative condition should help.

no, the derivative condition is so complex that I can't judge it. can anybody have concrete method and answer it?
